# custom composite unique on multiple columns with date field 

Tags: sql-server-2008, database-design

I have a table voucher_master. I want to make composite unique key which satisfies the below condition

```
voucher_type    voucher_sub_type     date        Abbreviation
 INV                DOM              1/1/2000       ID            allowed
 INV                DOM              15/1/2000      ID            allowed

 INV                INT              1/1/2000       ID            not allowed
 INV                INT              15/3/2012      ID            not allowed
```

If a particular `abbreviation` is created for `voucher_type` and `voucher_sub_type` then the same `abbreviation` cannot be created for any combination of `voucher_type` and `voucher_sub_type`.

However, if the abbreviation is created for a voucher_type and voucher_sub_type then the same abbreviation can be created with a difference of date for the same combination for which it was originally made. The same abbreviation cannot be created for any other combination.

How to do this in sql server?

Comment: Please someone any ideas or suggestion. It is urgent

Comment: i am not sure i understand your question properly. Do you want 2 of those columns to be the unique key meaning those 2 columns cant have any duplicate entries and all others can?

Comment: If a particular abbreviation is created for voucher_type and voucher_sub_type then the same abbreviation cannot be created for any combination of voucher_type and voucher_sub_type. However, if the abbreviation is created for a voucher_type and voucher_sub_type then the same abbreviation can be created with a difference of date for the same combination for which it was originally made. The same abbreviation cannot be created for any other combination.

Comment: sp then according to your logic this would be allowed ? INV DOM 15/3/2000 ID allowed ??

Comment: i have a question for you, why do you need a composite unique key? In my opinion that would be tough, why not use 'if' statements along with 'select/where' statements to find if your conditions match and if they do then the 'if' statement triggers and you insert the record. This would be much simpler IMHO.

Comment: Check back up in a few mins I will try to type out the statement for you...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks all,

I solved the problem with stored procedure and checked the required condition during insert and update

Answer (score 2):

I think that your requirements mean that the table should be normalized into 2 tables:

**Voucher**
 where both `Abbreviation` and `(voucher_type, voucher_sub_type)` are `UNIQUE`:

```
voucher_type   voucher_sub_type   Abbreviation
  INV            DOM                ID          allowed
  INV            INT                ID     not allowed (if the above row exists)
```

**Voucher_Dates**
 where `Abbreviation` is a `FOREIGN KEY` to `Voucher(Abbreviation)` and
`(date, Abbreviation)` is either `PRIMARY` or `UNIQUE`:

```
 date        Abbreviation
1/1/2000       ID           
15/1/2000      ID
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not good with syntax of SQL in server 2008 so I will write pseudo code and you can hopefully write code..

if (date!=@newDate where voucher_type=@newVoucher AND voucher_SubType=@newSubVoucher) THEN
{
insert record
}

What the above will do is compare to see if there exists a date with the same voucher types as the ones you are trying to insert it as and if there arent then you can enter the record. There is probably a lot of room for improvement but I hope someone can edit and add more to help you out.